# mysql - give a query as value (dynamic value)

Tags: mysql

Can I give a query as a value in mysql?

I meen something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET val='X'
```

where

```
X= SELECT COUNT(page) AS X FROM table2 WHERE order_no=1
```

so every time I ask for X it should depend on other tables content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `subquery` for your value, example

```
UPDATE table1 
SET val = (
           SELECT COUNT(page) 
           FROM table2 
           WHERE order_no = 1
          )
```

Comment: I got this:
`Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '(SELECT COUNT(page) FROM table2 WHERE id=1)' for column 'fajlok_szama' at row 1`